# How to calculate average from webelement list?

Tags: python, selenium, average

I chose the price list from WebElements. How can I calculate the price average?

I try use `len()` and `sum()` but it's not working.

```
price = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")
for i in price:
    value = i.text
    print(value)
```

output:

```
€4.44
€3.32
€3.93
€3.78
€4.06
```

Edit.
I find WebElement list using a CSS selector:

```
price = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")
```

This element list have 5 prices:

```
€4.44
€3.32
€3.93
€3.78
€4.06
```

I want to calculate average prices but I can't because this is WebElement List. I tried to extract this number without € by decimals:

```
price = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")
for i in price:
    value_price = i.text
    value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', value_price))
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
4.44
3.32
3.93
3.78
4.06
```

And now I want to calculate average this numbers:

```
price = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")
for i in price:
    value_price = i.text
    value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', value_price))
    print(value)
avg = sum(value)/len(value)
print(avg)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sokal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\login_sorare.py", line 56, in <module>
    avg = sum(value)/len(value)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable
```

I'm not sure what's wrong because I can't use `sum()`/`len()`.

Comment: How did you chose the price list from webelements?

Comment: Please read [what a minimal, reproducible example looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm using css selector

Comment: Have you removed the Euro symbol before trying to do math with the values? Also can you show us how the element looks like in the page and what is the HTML code for this element?

Comment: I edit my post and I think so clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum()` and `len()` are expecting a list but you are passing in just one value. That's why you are getting the `object is not iterable` error. There are a number of ways you can do this. One way is to take your existing code, add each `.text` value to an array, and then use `sum()` and `len()` to calculate the average.

```
price_elements = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")
text_prices = [price_element.text for price_element in price_elements]
prices = [float(text_price.replace('€', '')) for text_price in text_prices]
average = sum(prices)/len(prices)
print(average)
```

...and it prints

```
3.9059999999999997
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me. I tested the code I posted and it works.

Comment: What does not working mean? Is it throwing an error or ? Please post any error message or clearly explain what specifically is not working.

Comment: thank you for your answer.   I try your code.

price_elements = browser.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="p.sc-gKPRtg.sc-cTVMo.gFSBHP.dJSocd")

for i in price_elements:

    text_prices = [i.text for price_element in price_elements]
    prices = [float(text_price.replace('€', '')) for text_price in text_prices]
    average = sum(prices) / len(prices)
    print(average)

Output:
77.26
75.16
78.47
73.06
73.99

This is exacly the same number from website.
This is not average.

Comment: What you are using is not my code. You have my code mixed in with your code. Completely replace your code with mine. It works because I've tested it. It will print the average. `for i in price_elements:` should not be there if you are using exclusively my code.

Comment: I have a error. Output: File "C:\Users\sokal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\login_sorare.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
    text_prices = [i.text for price_element in price_elements]
                   ^
NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?

Comment: Sorry, `i` should have been `price_element`. I fixed it earlier but then reverted that change somehow. I've updated my answer with the fix.